# WiX Toolset add ODBC-32 Manager shortcut into Startmenu

Tags: wix, shortcut

At the moment I'm creating a setup script with WiX Toolset. I can not find a solution, how to add a shortcut of ODBC-32 Manager into Startmenu of my App. Has anyone a tip (code snippet), how to solve this problem?

Comment: Could you just launch that tool directly from your application? Tools menu? Toolbar icon? Much easier to maintain and use? The file is at: C:\WINDOWS\SysWOW64\odbcad32.exe. You can also have a look at [the bottom sample here](https://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/howtos/files_and_registry/create_uninstall_shortcut.html) (unless you have already found it). [Also check github.com for "samples"](https://github.com/search?q=%3CShortcut+%3CWix+extension%3Awxs&type=Code).

Comment: Maybe check [the "Shortcut" section here](https://learn.microsoft.com/nb-no/archive/blogs/alexshev/from-msi-to-wix) (part 10). Look at the very bottom, [a downloadable zip of samples](https://msdnshared.blob.core.windows.net/media/TNBlogsFS/prod.evol.blogs.technet.com/telligent.evolution.components.attachments/01/5053/00/00/02/91/69/85/Shortcuts.zip). Dated content, but very good.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If someone is interesting, here is a code snipped, to create a ODBC manager shortcut

```
<Component Id="cmp_extra_shortcuts" Guid="*">
    <!-- ODBC Manager shortcut -->
    <Shortcut
        Id="*"
        Name="ODBC Manager (32-Bit)"
        Target="[SystemFolder]odbcad32.exe"
        Description="Windows ODBC Manager (32-Bit)"
        Directory="ProgramMenuToolsDir"
        Advertise="no"
        WorkingDirectory="PRODUCTFOLDER"
        Show="normal"/>

    <RegistryValue
        Root="HKCU"
        Key="Software\$(var.CompanyFolder)\$(var.ApplicationNameWithVersion)"
        Name="Installed"
        Type="integer"
        Value="1"
        KeyPath="yes"/>
</Component>
```

I hope someone helps it.